# How to get AttributeSet object from a View?

Tags: android, view

i have a initialised View as

```
View v = new View (this); 
v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
```

i want to pass this view to a method  say `METHOD(View v)` which later need the AttributeSet

i have to re-pass the values after i already defined as.

```
Method(View v , int Width , int height)
```

Is there any way to get AttributeSet object from view .

`v.getWidth();` and `v.getHeight();` are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really [take a look at the android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29).

To retrieve that value you can either retrieve the LayoutParams you set OR, if the view has been already laid out you can retrieve them by using [getMeasuredHeight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight%28%29) or [getMeasuredWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredWidth%28%29)